# Need help to complete the DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

Here is the scenario.

http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4451/capture1iw.png

I have created a dtd for there 4 recipes.But you can see in coffee butterfly cakes and coffee moroccan chicken recipes there are ingredients for Icing and Sause as well.But I don't know how to indicate that in my dtd.So please help me to modify it.Thank you.

Here is my dtd.

```
<!DOCTYPE cookbook[
<!ELEMENT cookbook ( recipe+ ) >
<!ATTLIST recipe xml:id NMTOKEN #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT recipe ( title, ingredient+, time, method ) >
<!ATTLIST recipe servings(serves|makes) CDATA #REQUIRED >

<!ELEMENT title ( #PCDATA ) >

<!ELEMENT ingredient EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST ingredient name CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ATTLIST ingredient quantity CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ATTLIST ingredient unit(tsp|number|g|oz|tab|ml|pt) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST ingredient brand CDATA #IMPLIED >

<!ELEMENT time EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST time quantity NMTOKEN #REQUIRED >
<!ATTLIST time unit NMTOKEN #REQUIRED >

<!ELEMENT method ( step+ ) >
<!ELEMENT step ( #PCDATA ) >

]>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that for Icing and Sause ingredient 'quantity', 'unit', and 'brand' are not present. So you may put these attribute at #IMPLIED instead of #REQUIRED, or you may put deault value for those as N/A